# Akka stream broadcast in java

Tags: java, akka-stream

I am trying to broadcast to 2 sink from a source in java, got stuck in between, any pointer will be helpful

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {


        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("GraphBasics");
        ActorMaterializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

        final Source<Integer, NotUsed> source = Source.range(1, 1000);
         Sink<Integer,CompletionStage<Done>> firstSink = Sink.foreach(x -> System.out.println("first sink "+x));
        Sink<Integer,CompletionStage<Done>> secondsink  = Sink.foreach(x -> System.out.println("second sink "+x));


                RunnableGraph.fromGraph(
                GraphDSL.create(
                        b -> {
                            UniformFanOutShape<Integer, Integer> bcast = b.add(Broadcast.create(2));


                            b.from(b.add(source)).viaFanOut(bcast).to(b.add(firstSink)).to(b.add(secondsink));


                            return ClosedShape.getInstance();
                        }))
                .run(materializer);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

i am not that much familiar with java api for akka-stream graphs, so i used the [official doc](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-graphs.html). there are 2 errors in your snippet:

1. when you added source to the graph builder, you need to get `Outlet` from it. so instead of `b.from(b.add(source))` there should smth like this: `b.from(b.add(source).out())` according to the official doc
2. you can't just call two `.to` method in a row, because `.to` expects smth with `Sink` shape, which means kind of dead end. instead you need to attach 2nd sink to the bcast directly, like this:

   ```
   (...).viaFanOut(bcast).to(b.add(firstSink));
   b.from(bcast).to(b.add(secondSink));
   ```

all in all the code should look like this:

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("GraphBasics");
ActorMaterializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

final Source<Integer, NotUsed> source = Source.range(1, 1000);
Sink<Integer, CompletionStage<Done>> firstSink = foreach(x -> System.out.println("first sink " + x));
Sink<Integer, CompletionStage<Done>> secondSink = foreach(x -> System.out.println("second sink " + x));


RunnableGraph.fromGraph(
        GraphDSL.create(b -> {
                    UniformFanOutShape<Integer, Integer> bcast = b.add(Broadcast.create(2));

                    b.from(b.add(source).out()).viaFanOut(bcast).to(b.add(firstSink));
                    b.from(bcast).to(b.add(secondSink));

                    return ClosedShape.getInstance();
                }
        )
).run(materializer);
```

Final note - i would think twice whether it makes sense to use graph api. If you case as simple as this one (just 2 sinks), you might want just to use [alsoTo](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/Flow.html#alsoTo(that:akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SinkShape[Out],_]):akka.stream.javadsl.Flow[In,Out,Mat]) or [alsoToMat](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/stream/javadsl/Flow.html#alsoToMat[M2,M3](that:akka.stream.Graph[akka.stream.SinkShape[Out],M2],matF:akka.japi.function.Function2[Mat,M2,M3]):akka.stream.javadsl.Flow[In,Out,M3]). They give you the possibility to attach multiple sinks to the flow without the need to use graphs.